# how to make a connection to an existing Redshift database using JDBC driver and Boto3 API in Python

Tags: python, jdbc, connection, amazon-redshift, boto3

I do not know how to write a connection string in Python using Boto3 API to make a jdbc connection to an existing database on AWS Redshift.  I am using MobaXterm or putty to make a SSH connection.  I have some codes to create the table, but am lost as to how to connect to the Database in Redshift

```
import boto3

s3client = boto3.client('redshift', config=client-config)

CREATE TABLE pheaapoc_schema.green_201601_csv (
    vendorid varchar(4),
    pickup_ddatetime TIMESTAMP,
    dropoff_datetime TIMESTAMP,
```

I need to connect to database "dummy" and create a table.

Comment: You connect with `psycopg2`, not boto3. boto3 is for interacting with the AWS API.

Comment: So I can't connect with JDBC

Comment: JDBC is for Java, not for Python.

Comment: Ok, so I use psycopg2, I still don't get the format for the connection string.  I have an endpoint and an IAM credential, so it's what conn =psycopg2.db=endpoint + dbname+credential??  How bout showing me an example please, let's say my database is dummy on us-east1  how would that look roughly?

Comment: you dont need/use iam credentials, you need redshift credentials. different thing. the format is pretty much identical to postgres so you can look that up. and read this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-odbc-connection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TL;DR; You do not need IAM credentials or boto3 to connect to Redshift. What you need is end_point for the Redshift cluster and redshift credentials and a postgres client using which you can connect.

**You can connect to Redshift cluster just the way you connect to any Database** (Like MySQL, PostgreSQL or MongoDB). To connect to any database, you need 5 items.

1. host - (This is nothing but the end point you get from AWS console/Redshift)
2. username - (Refer again to AWS console/Redshift. Take a look at master username section)
3. password - (If you created the Redshift, you should know the password for master user)
4. port number - (5439 for Redshift)
5. Database - (The default database you created at first)

Refer to the screenshot if it is not intuitive.

**What boto3 APIs do?**

Boto3 provides APIs using which you can modify your Redshift cluster. For example, it provides APIs to delete your cluster, resize your cluster or take a snapshot of your cluster. They do not involve connection whatsoever.

**Screenshots for reference:**

[image: End point]

[image: AWS console]